# Will I die if I ask for my death during azan?

Tags: allah

I have been going through mental stress. During azan I said "I wish I die" after realizing what I said I immediately said "God please don't do this, don't kill me". Now what will happen to me? I don't want my life to end... please reply..

Comment: Why don't you wait and find out?

Comment: Salam please be aware that IslamStackExchange is a question and answer site about Islam and not a typical internet forum. I strongly recommend you to check our [help] and take our [tour] before asking the next off-topic question or posting somethinh which lacks any prior research efforts nor elaboration.

Comment: Some scholars say that making bad dua on yourself ( sth that returns harm to you ) are not accepted initially

Answer (score 0):

You should have no worries about your death, as soon you realises that you did wrong, so never afraid, allah is the most merciful, there is a specefic time for each person's death, so you will not die until your time comes,.
ALLAH KNOWS BETTER